# how to make a voice recorder

Tags: java, android

I want to make a voice recorder so that my client can record the voice note and upload it to the system then the manager can review as voice note. Please, I don't know where to start. thanks.

[what show when i use chrome to upload to my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vET2L.png)

[What show when I try to upload from my android app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXuhM.png)

my Java code i used from the

```
package com.pemasoft.checklistsystem;
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private final static int FCR = 1;
    private WebView webView;
    private String mCM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            Uri[] results = null;

            //Check if response is positive
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == FCR) {

                    if (null == mUMA) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (intent == null) {
                        //Capture Photo if no image available
                        if (mCM != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                        }
                    } else {
                        String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                        if (dataString != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
            mUMA = null;
        } else {

            if (requestCode == FCR) {
                if (null == mUM) return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUM = null;
            }
        }
    }

    //private WebView My_Web_View;
    @SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        this.getSupportActionBar().hide();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
        }

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mwebview);
        assert webView != null;

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        //webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.OFF);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30");
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().supportZoom();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            webSettings.setMixedContentMode(0);
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

        webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());

        if (isNetworkAvailable() == true) {
            webView.loadUrl("https://app.enterprise360.co/mobile/");
        } else {
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/main.html");
        }
        //
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            //For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FCR);
            }

            // For Android 3.0+, above method not supported in some android 3+ versions, in such case we use this
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {

                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                        FCR);
            }

            //For Android 4.1+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {

                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), MainActivity.FCR);
            }

            //For Android 5.0+
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

                if (mUMA != null) {
                    mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
                }

                mUMA = filePathCallback;
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {

                    File photoFile = null;

                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                    }
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }

                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
                Intent[] intentArray;

                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);

                return true;
            }
        });
        //
    }

    // Create an image file
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "img_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event) {

//        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
//
//            switch (keyCode) {
//                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
//
//                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
//                        webView.goBack();
//                    } else {
//                        finish();
//                    }
//
//                    return true;
//            }
//        }
//
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        //return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public class Callback extends WebViewClient {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed loading app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    boolean isNetworkAvailable() {

        boolean isConnected = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (cm != null && (
                (cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) ||
                        (cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED))) {
            isConnected = true;
            //You are connected, do something online.

        } else if (cm != null && (
                (cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) ||
                        (cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED))) {

            isConnected = false;

            //Not connected.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You must be connected to the internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return isConnected;

        //ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        //NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        //boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        //return isConnected;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think our question is demanding a tutorial. Try this one:

https://medium.com/@ssaurel/create-an-audio-recorder-for-android-94dc7874f3d

Comment: This is a hyper application not native can you tell me how I can merge this code into hyper application

Comment: That link will help you to build a voice recorder. After recording, upload voice file to a server. 
If you don't know how to upload then you should take help from video tutorials.

Comment: I know how to upload the file but how to add record option into the dialog this I didn't know to do. Plz review the 2 picture this what I am stuck on it now.